# Shared internet connection is blocked by firewall

Tags: networking, windows-10, firewall, ics

my Windows Firewall blocks internet access for connected devices via Internet Connection Sharing (ICS).

**Problem**

On my Windows 10 Pro (1607) machine (HP ProBook 450 G4), I want to share my wired Ethernet internet connection via WiFi.
I want to use this connection with my HTC One m7 device.
When I activate a mobile hotspot under Settings > Network & Internet > Mobile hotspot all looks fine.
I connect my phone to this new WiFi and open chrome browser. When I try to open a website I see an error: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

When I deactivate Windows Firewall for public networks it works fine, connections to internet server can be established.

When I check Network and Sharing Center, I see two active networks: One private one with two connections (Ethernet and WiFi) and one public one with one connection ("LAN connection* 13").

**Question**

So actually, I get it to work, but I don't want to leave my firewall deactivated, especially for public networks. Does anyone know which rule I have to add to my firewall settings to permanently allow all traffic passing through from and to "LAN connection* 13"?
(Just to be clear, I don't need port forwarding through Window's NAT, I just want to allow devices in the shared connection to use internet.)

Comment: Reset firewall rules in control panel.

Comment: I did but still no connection

Answer (score 1):

You say: "When I deactivate Windows Firewall for public networks it works fine",
from which I gather that the WiFi network is defined as Public.
This means that Windows offers the maximum protection possible from
other devices on the same network, because it treats that network as
untrusted.

I suggest to change the WiFi network to be Private, to enable placing
trust in the local devices. Remember to undo this when using public
hotspots.

To change the network type (while WiFi is connected):

- Open *Settings > Network & Internet > Status*
- Click the Properties button situated below the network name
- Set the "Network prof‌ile" to Private

Reboot might be required for this to take effect.

Comment: Wow, there is really no way to find out, if this the correct answer :(

Comment: Why not? Just change the network type and see if it works.

Comment: Well, first I have to rewind my system to the state nearly five years ago. Well, after I found the laptop I had back then.

Comment: Maybe @truthseeker can verify it, assuming that your post corresponds exactly to his case.